# Undeclared Identifier in Payable Function

Tags: contract-development, gas, nft, test

I want to call a contracts functions from another contract for hardhat-gas-reporter purposes however I keep getting undeclared identifier here. What am I doing wrong?

```
contract BaseRosie is Ownable, ERC721A, ReentrancyGuard {
constructor() ERC721A("Rosie", "ROSIE") {}

    function publicSaleMint(uint256 mintAmount)
        external
        payable
    {
        _safeMint(msg.sender, mintAmount);
    }
}
```

```
contract RosieMock is BaseRosie{
    constructor() BaseRosie() {}

    function mintOnePublic(uint256 mintAmount) public payable {
        publicSaleMint{value: msg.value}(msg.sender)(mintAmount);
    }
}
```

The mintOnePublic function gives me the "undeclared identifier" error.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty confusing lol.

If you are trying to interact with deployed contract then you first need to set the variable like this:

```
NameOfTheContract public contract = NameOfTheContract("addressOfTheDeployedContract")
```

Then you can call functions on that contract like this:

```
contract.publicSaleMint{value: msg.value}(mintAmount);
```

Also here:

```
publicSaleMint{value: msg.value}(msg.sender)(mintAmount);
```

why is there msg.sender?